# Recording Values from Workbook_1 onto Workbook_2

Tags: excel, vba, record, rtd

Having issues linking the values from Workbook_1 to appear on Workbook_2. I am not seeing the syntax error. Set Capture line is flagged. Any help much appreciated.

```
Sub RecordData()
Dim NextTime As Date
Dim Interval As Double
Dim cel As Range
Dim Capture As Range

Application.StatusBar = "Recording Started"
Set Capture = Workbooks("Workbook_1.xlsm").Worksheets(“Dashboard”).Range("A22:B22") 'Capture this row of data from Workbook_1
With Worksheets("Log") 'Record the data from Workbook_1 on this sheet on Workbook_2
    Set cel = .Range("A2") 'First timestamp goes here
    Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    cel.Value = Now
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Capture.Rows.Count, Capture.Columns.Count).Value = Capture.Value
End With
NextTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is flagged? Do you actually have the smart quotes in `“Dashboard”`? They should be straight quotes.

Comment: Oh man...good eye. You could be right....checking now.

Comment: Good lord. That was it. I stared at it for like 3hrs and didn't see that. It works now. So annoying thanks.

Comment: @BigBen I was staring at the line thinking I was going mad. `Application.Workbooks("Workbook_1.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Name = "Dashboard"` So why is it an error when I ask for `Workbooks("Workbook_1.xlsm").Worksheets(“Dashboard”).Name` ?! darn weird quotes.